# dynamically loading angular directives not being added to $compileProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, lazy-loading

I can not for the life of me figure out why this is not working. The directive file is loading but the actual directive isn't being loaded into angular as it should at defer.resolve() in the routeProvider.js like it should.

I have been using these two examples as references but as of yet havent figured out why it is not working.

https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs 
https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager

**Dynamic route**

```
console.log('Log: initializing Providers');
        app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
        app.service = $provide.service;
        app.factory = $provide.factory;
        app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
        app.directive = $compileProvider.directive;

        var route = routeResolverProvider.route;

        console.log('Log: initializing Routes');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                route.resolve({
                    module:'start',
                    directives: ['moduleButton']
                })
            )
```

**RouteProvider.js**

```
define(['angular'], function () {
/**
 * this service returns a valid route definition object
 * for the angular route 'when' method
 *
 * @type {*|module}
 */
angular.module('routeResolver', [])

    .provider('routeResolver', function () {

        this.$get = function () {
            return this;
        };

        /**
         * configuration object
         */
        this.routeConfig = (function () {

            var serviceDirectory = 'scripts/services/',
                viewsDirectory = 'views/',
                modulesDirectory = 'data/',
                directiveDirectory = 'scripts/directives',

                setServiceDirectory = function (serviceDir) {
                    serviceDirectory = serviceDir + '/';
                },

                getServiceDirectory = function () {
                    return serviceDirectory;
                },

                setViewsDirectory = function (viewsDir) {
                    viewsDirectory = viewsDir + '/';
                },

                getViewsDirectory = function () {
                    return viewsDirectory;
                },
                getModuleDirectoy = function () {
                    return   modulesDirectory;
                },
                setModuleDirectory = function (moduleDir) {
                    modulesDirectory = 'data/' + moduleDir + '/';
                },
                getDirectiveDirectory = function(){
                    return directiveDirectory;
                },
                setDirectiveDirectory = function(directiveDir){
                    directiveDirectory = directiveDir + '/';
                }
            return {
                getModuleDirectory: getModuleDirectoy,
                setModuleDirectory: setModuleDirectory,
                setServiceDirectory: setServiceDirectory,
                getServiceDirectory: getServiceDirectory,
                setViewsDirectory: setViewsDirectory,
                getViewsDirectory: getViewsDirectory,
                getDirectiveDirectory: getDirectiveDirectory,
                setDirectiveDirectory: setDirectiveDirectory

            };
        }());

        /**
         * build and return the route definiation object
         */
        this.route = function (routeConfig) {

            var resolve = function (data) {

                    var viewDir;
                    var view = 'view' in data ? data.view : "index";
                    var module = 'module' in data ? data.module : "";
                    var services = 'service' in data ? data.services : [];
                    var directives = 'directives' in data ? data.directives : [];
                    if (view != 'index') {
                        viewDir = view + '/';
                    } else {
                        viewDir = '';
                    }

                    var routeDef = {};

                    routeConfig.setModuleDirectory(module);
                    routeConfig.setViewsDirectory(routeConfig.getModuleDirectory() + viewDir);
                    routeConfig.setDirectiveDirectory(routeConfig.getModuleDirectory() + routeConfig.getDirectiveDirectory());

                    routeDef.templateUrl = routeConfig.getViewsDirectory() + viewDir + view + '.html';
                    routeDef.controller = view + 'Ctrl';
                    routeDef.resolve = {

                        load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {

                            /**
                             * init the dependencies array
                             * @type {Array}
                             */
                            var dependencies = [routeConfig.getViewsDirectory() + viewDir + view + '.js'];

                            /**
                             * add data.services to dependencies array
                             */
                            if (services) {
                                var service;
                                for (service in services) {
                                    if (services.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
                                        dependencies.push(routeConfig.getServiceDirectory() + services[service] + '.js');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(directives){
                                var directive;
                                for(directive in directives){
                                    if(directives.hasOwnProperty(directive)){
                                        dependencies.push(routeConfig.getDirectiveDirectory() + directives[directive] + '.js');

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
                        }]
                    };

                    return routeDef;
                },

                /**
                 * load the required dependencies, resolve
                 * a promise on success
                 * @param $q
                 * @param $rootScope
                 * @param dependencies
                 * @returns {Function|promise}
                 */
                    resolveDependencies = function ($q, $rootScope, dependencies) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    require(dependencies, function () {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                            defer.resolve();
                        });
                    });

                    return defer.promise;
                };

            return {
                resolve: resolve
            }

        }(this.routeConfig);

    });
});
```

**ModuleButton.js**

```
define(['app'],function(app){
   app.directive('moduleButton',function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '../views/moduleButton/moduleButton.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {

        },
        link: function(){
            console.log('hi');
        }

     }
  });
});
```